# load files from two different folders in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-load

Hi and I am little bit new in matlab.
I have two different folders in my laptop, each one contains about 400 different files. I want to load all these files (400 from first folder and 400 from second folder), I tried like that but doesn't work:

```
folder1=('E:\results\1\'); 
folder2=('E:\results\2\'); 
data=load([folder1,'*.m']);
data1=load([folder2,'*.m']);
```

and then I want to take first file from folder1 and subtracted from first file from folder1 and save it in new folder. and do that for all other files ... etc
can some expert give me any suggerstion!!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure `load` takes one file at a time.  Try a simple variant like this:

```
folder1=('E:\results\1\'); 
folder2=('E:\results\2\');
files1 = dir( [folder1,'*.m'] );
files2 = dir( [folder2,'*.m'] );

data = cell(length(files1),1);  % I don't know what's in the mat files, but let's start with a cell array
data1 = cell(length(files2),1);
for ii=1:length(files1)
  data{ii} = load(fullfile(folder1,files1(ii).name));
end
for ii=1:length(files2)
  data1{ii} = load(fullfile(folder2,files2(ii).name));
end
```

There are other, more one liner ways, but this is a fairly pedantic.

Comment: hi, thanks alot. but I think cell command does not work for me. in these files I have matrix which contains 3 columns and 500 rows. each pixel in matrix contain numbers.. is there other better command for my case

Comment: @user2486405, depends on how you want to use the data.  In any course, a cell array is a *super* container that can store just about anything, including a 500x3 matrix, so `data` is a cell array, with each entry containing a 500x3 matrix.